Create an alias in bashrc file
In Linux terminal, normally I can copy files from another unix server using:
scp -r myname@institute.edu:/data/filename ./

which secure copies the remote file to my current directory. I've made sure this command line works well before I did anything below.
To save time of typing the long front part, I create an alias for scp -r myname@institute.edu:, and receive arguments for /data/filename and ./ from command line.
Opening the ~/.bashrc file, first I tried
alias scpfile="scp -r myname@institute.edu:'$1' '$2'"

In command line, I typed scpfile /data/filename ./,
but I got an error message as follows:
error: unexpected filename: .

Then I tried another one
function scpfile() {
    scp -r myname@institute.edu:$1 $(pwd)
}

or
function scpfile() {
    scp -r myname@institute.edu:"$1" "$(pwd)"
}

In command line, I typed scpfile /data/filename,
but it's also wrong with error message:
/data/filename: No such file or directory

Can someone help if you know the answer to it?
Moreover, I've tried the answers shown in Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter, but still not working!

I noticed this post and tried the answers. However, none of them worked in my case.

If I'm correct, your second function "doesn't work" due to missing quotes (scp -r myname@institute.edu:"$1" "$(pwd)" should be fine). If that also fails for you, post more details, including full error message.

fwiw, the function (edited for my login name and local host) works as long as the remote directory/file combo, as well as the local pwd, contains no whitespace; if either contains white space then I get an error message scp: /path/to/invalid/file: No such file or directory

Hi All, those errors are exactly what I got in my machine. If I type the full line, as the first code line shows, there's no any problem.

The error is more indicative of the remote file not existing than any problem with your function definition (though $1 and $(pwd)--or better, $PWD--should both be quoted).

It may be easier to configure the user name for that server in your  ~/.ssh/config and then the command is just scp edu:/some/file .

what about
alias home2edu='edu_put() { scp -r $@ myname@institute.edu: ; }; edu_put'
and
alias edu2home='edu_get() { scp -r myname@institute.edu:$@ . ; }; edu_get'

@yvs2014 It doesn't make sense for an alias to be redefining a function each time that alias it iinvoked. Why wouldn't you just call that function home2edu and drop the alias.

@Kaz your remark (or question) is out of scope TS q

Your alias definition does not make sense. $1 and $2 would be empty. However your second function definition looks reasonable. The error message is odd; I would expect that it is prefixed by scp: .... Please post a screenshot from which we can see your function definition, the way you call your function, and the error message you get. BTW, what's the point in calling pwd? You could simply write a sole ., which always denotes the working directory.

The Bash documentation (Info manual) says:

There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, use a shell function (see Shell Functions).

and

For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.

If you need to develop a custom command that takes argument to which it can refer by position, you write a function.
This looks right:
function scpfile() {
    scp -r myname@institute.edu:"$1" "$(pwd)" 
}

Except, there is no advantage of using "$(pwd)" over just . (period), and it is less efficient, too.  You would only need that in order to given a path argument to some tool that insists on requiring absolute paths.
The error message about the non-existence of $1 is coming from the remote host. scp is finding that /data/filename does not exist on the remote host.

The function keyword and () are redundant. Use either one, though the later is the preferred most portable way. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023942/whats-the-use-of-parentheses-in-shell-function-definition#comment1663585_1023947

@LéaGris Good catch.
